# What is the difference between Dutch Pie and German Pie?

Tags: pie

I've seen several recipes of the two pies and even then I don't know if there is an original.

Usually in Dutch Pie in Brazil, [picture here](http://prnt.sc/bxh2co), I see it based on a dough made with melted butter and crushed crackers. As filling a crème pâtissière and a dark chocolate ganache.

In German Pie in Brazil, [picture here](http://prnt.sc/bxh1wj), I never found something "canonical", but usually see it surrounded with chocolate-covered cookies. In fact, I don't know which is used in this pie filling and which procedure should be taken to do it.

Comment: You do realize that there is no traditional "German pie" in Germany? At least not as far as I know and I am German...

Comment: Yes. This is the question. Here in Brazil commonly exist both of these pie were named as well.

Comment: I think those are both Brazilian dishes. Interesting side note, at least in the eastern US, a "dutch pie" would be a Dutch apple pie, named after the [Pennsylvania Dutch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pennsylvania_Dutch) who are from Germany (not the Netherlands). Presumably from *Deutsch* being changed to Dutch over the centuries. I wonder if something similar has occurred in Brazil.

Comment: OK, I am deleting all comments pertaining to there not being Dutch pies in the Netherlands and German pies in Germany. It is normal that people call "exotic" forms of a food after the land in which they have had it, they don't call their "standard" form after their own country. If somebody needs to discuss the linguistics any deeper, it will need a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The one called, "Dutch pie" is typically a very smooth pie on a cookie base. The one called, "German pie" generally has a layer of crushed nuts on top of the smooth chocolate icing.